# "ERROR: Cannot recover key" When Exporting Signed Android App with Existing Keystore

Tags: android, export, apk, keystore, android-keystore

I have an existing keystore with a password and a few keys with different passwords inside for the different apps I have exported and uploaded to Google Play.

Now I have recently imported one of the app's projects, did some significant modifications to it and I am trying to export it using the same keystore and choosing the same alias/password as I did while initially creating it.

The problem is that after the step where I choose the key alias and enter key password I see "**ERROR: Cannot recover key**".

[image]

I suspect that I might be entering a wrong key password (note that the keystore password is the correct one, so this is not the reason for the issue).

I tried creating a new alias and exporting the app under it, but Google Play won't accept this file unless it's signed with the same certificate.

I really don't know how to proceed in this scenario besides trying to brute force the key password. If you think this is the only path, do you know a good brute force cracking tool for keys in a keystore, for which I already know the password to? The keystore is a .reg file, created with Eclipse's Export wizard.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Pretty sure you just entered the password incorrectly. Happened to me just now, stumbled upon your question, hoping for an answer. Didn't find any, so I tried typing the password again. And then it worked.

Comment: hello I actually have my keystore certificate and also I remember my keystore password and inside the dropdown I can see the Alias name I used to sign the apk but I have forgotten the password in the key alias section , can it be recovered somehow.

Comment: A strange quirk I discovered: (using adt 22.3 and probably prior versions) Once you have entered an incorrect key password (not keystore paswword) you are "locked out" from further attempts until you close the Export Android Application dialog.  You cannot simply press the back button and try again.

Comment: I did it twice incorrectly, came here, read your answer, tried again and then it worked. Could be that i closed the dialog meanwhile though like Hugh Jeffner described.

Comment: For me, the problem was one of the keys on my keyboard was stuck. realized it only after typing it in an editor to see what i was actually typing in as the password.

Comment: For me i realised that even after entering the incorrect password 5 times it accepted the last attempt (even though it was wrong) which caused the error and then, because i had chosen to remember the passwords it was using the wrong passwords for all the following builds. So i restarted Android Studio and it worked :)

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon the same problem. But I was sure I entered the password correctly. I even typed it to notepad and copy-pasted it to be sure. After that, I created a password cracker for my keystore key password, and found out that the key was actually the one I had been using all along! Tried once more and it worked. So I guess it was a bug of some kind. Maybe you should try closing and reopening eclipse, or restart the computer.

Comment: On a side note, can you share the password cracker that you used for this? I happen to forget my keystore passwords very often.

Comment: @WordPressDeveloper Custom password cracker i created to check amongst the hundreds of variations i use for my passwords. Not really useful for anyone else.

Comment: I can verify this. I use Android Studio. After just restarting it, it would accept my passwords again. I had two projects open at the same time and I think this has to do with it. The passwords were also not remembered by AS, which never happens.